# Meteor Flow Router React: I am passing a component as a prop, and I want to include a prop in that component

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

See this code:

```
authenticatedRoutes.route( '/study/:studyId/study_settings', {
  name: 'study_settings',
  action(params, queryParams) {
    console.log(queryParams);
    Session.set('studyId', params.studyId);
    mount( Default, { yield: <PageContainer pageName='Study Settings' page={<StudySettings />}/>  } );
  }
});
```

As you can see the `page` prop? in the mount function? I am passing `<StudySettings />` component

well I want to pass a prop into this component

but when I try `<StudySettings queryPage=queryParams.subPage />` I get compile error.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pass a prop to a ReactJS Component that is a variable you need to use `{}` so in your case you need to do something like this

`<StudySettings queryPage={ queryParams.subPage } />`

Let me know if you have anyother questions!